# Knex migrations with Postgres always say 'Already up to date'

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I am trying to alter my Postgres database using Knex migrations but they are not working.

My knexfile.js looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  development: {
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
      database: 'cms_dev',
    },
  },
};
```

Then I have a `db.js` that looks like this:

```
const config = require('../knexfile.js');

const env = 'development';
const knex = require('knex')(config[env]);

module.exports = knex;

knex.migrate.latest([config]);
```

If I am starting with a fresh database my first migration works but if I try to update the database with a new (2nd) migration it does nothing.

When I try running `knex migrate:latest --env development` it says:

```
Using environment: development
Already up to date
```

*****EDIT*****

I ended up generating another new (3rd) migration and pasted in the exact same code from the previous one that was being ignored and it worked. No clue why the 2nd migration silently failed and the 3rd one worked.

Comment: flash your table `knex_migrations` and `knex_migrations_lock`

Comment: Were you trying to create an additional migration with each new database after running `knex migrate:latest` for the first time? Or were you just creating a new database and running `knex migrate:latest`, then trying to run it again and thinking it failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue. I had forgotten to configure `nodemon` to ignore my migrations folder.

Because I have this line in `db.js`:

```
knex.migrate.latest([config]);
```

If I saved at all while creating the migration, my server would restart and cause the latest and incomplete migration to fire off. Since migrations only run once, Knex would think the database was already up to date.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to re-run any migrations from the start, delete the migrations tables in the schema/database of your choice.